# Does anyone know, why I can´t get ALL document from a firebase Collection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This example brings me just one document from the collection ("socios"). Does anyone, explain what Im doing wrong????

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const consulta = async () => {
      const db = firebase.firestore();
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db,"socios"));
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log("ESTO ES DOCDATA", doc.data())
        setQuery(doc.data());
      });
    };
    consulta();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the problem is here:

Each time you call `setQuery`, the `doc.data()` overwrites any previous value you had in that state variable.

To keep all values, do something like:

```
let docs = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
setQuery(docs);
```

So now we put the data of all documents in an array, and then pass that array to `setQuery`. This of course means that your UI components also have to be able to render the array.

Comment: Dear Frank in the same way. When I use useFirestoreConnect (), and then useSelector() to get and store that value., everything its ok, when the component mount inn the first render. BUT, when I refresh the page, useSelector() brings me back an empty array. ...

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't ring a bell to me. You might want to post a new question with its own [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that others can check too.